# Identity Server 4 Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm following along with examples for how to implement [Identity Server 4](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4)

I'm trying to add in memory users in

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
  .AddInMemoryClients(new List<Client>())
  .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(new List<IdentityResource>())
  .AddInMemoryApiResources(new List<ApiResource>())
  .AddInMemoryUsers(new List<InMemoryUser>())
  .AddTemporarySigningCredential();
```

I'm receiving an error that there is no definition for`.AddInMemoryUsers(new List<InMemoryUser>())`

Can anyone point me where this dll is or if this has been remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's renamed to AddTestUsers, IdentityServer4 was updated since that blog.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Startup.cs